# Search for phrases inside youtube's closed captions

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I've searched all over the internet, but could not find out what happened to the caption search feature. Some time ago to the search query '"Some rare quote", cc' youtube would include links "Start playing at search term (1:03)" which indicates that the search result was obtained from the closed caption content. Here is the blog post about it: http://googlevideo.blogspot.ru/2008/06/closed-captioning-search-options.html

What happened to that feature? Am i the only one who thinks this was super useful? Is there any way of doing that through youtube's API?

Answer (score 0):

Checking the document - [Implementation and Migration: Search requests](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/search), you can search [videoCaption](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#videoCaption):

> The videoCaption parameter indicates whether the API should filter video search results based on whether they have captions. If you specify a value for this parameter, you must also set the [type](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#type) parameter's value to **`video`**.
>
> Acceptable values are:

- **any** – Do not filter results based on caption availability.
- **closedCaption** – Only include videos that have captions.
- **none** – Only include videos that do not have captions.

Yes, there is a search functionality of that but it is not available in Youtube API. As you can see in this blog - [Captions for all: more options for your viewing and reading pleasure](https://youtube.googleblog.com/2012/02/captions-for-all-more-options-for-your.html), this show the search capability using Youtube UI. You may want to file a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20(Enhancement%20Request)) for that.

Hope this helps.